# jquery on event remove all tags except span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a function that's exactly like

```
$str = striptags($str, 'span');
```

in PHP. I need the same type of function in jquery:

```
$("#str").on('click keydown keyup change keypress', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

???

)};
```

Is it simple like in PHP? or it's something more complicated?

Comment: You probably need a regular expression.

Comment: Are you just looking to just remove occurrences in a string, or from the DOM?

Comment: @Drumbeg it's a contenteditable div witch show the errors in span, other tags can disturb(...) it

Comment: @TimotheusTriebl This is the opposite of that thread. It's more akin to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128125/how-can-i-strip-all-regular-html-tags-except-a-a-imgattributes-inside-a

Comment: @AoN but hpow to implement that?

Comment: This might help out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript.  Go down to the Converting HTML for Plain Text emailing keeping hyperlinks (a href) intact answer.  It shows how to remove all tags besides <a> from the text.

Comment: @faq I've modified my answer to include a JSFiddle and added an `if` statement to test the parents of an element (that way the contents of a span will remain unaffected). I hope the JSFiddle helps to demonstrate how it could be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this jQuery a try:

```
$('#str').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').find('*').not('span').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

You'll have to adjust its target to whatever parent you want to clear the content of, but this should work.

**Edit**

I've updated it to account for if the element is contained in a span, at some point:

```
$('#str').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').find('*').not('span').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).parents().is('span')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

If you only want to accommodate for a single level up, replace `parents()` with `parent()` in the `if` statement.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y1r0wg2r/