# How to explode a string on <br/> tag

Tags: php

I have a string like following

```
Overall Queen Poster <br /> Queen Poster Headboard:<br /> Queen Poster <br /> Queen Footboard  <br /> Queen Poster Rails: 62.28"W x 84.02"D x 18.07"H - 37lbs.
```

How to explode it on 
 tag so that I can get the values in an array?

I tried this

```
   $myString =  "Overall Queen Poster <br /> Queen Poster Headboard:<br /> Queen Poster <br /> Queen Footboard  <br /> Queen Poster Rails: 62.28"W x 84.02"D x 18.07"H - 37lbs";
    $myArray = explode("\n",$myString);
    print_r($myArray);
```

But not getting correct result.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's because `<br />` != `\n`.

You can use regex to split it, to make sure that you get all the BR tags (`<br>`, `<br />`, `<br/>`, `<br class="break">`, `<BR>` etc.)

**Code**:

```
<?php
    $myString = 'Overall Queen Poster <br /> Queen Poster Headboard:<br /> Queen Poster <br /> Queen Footboard  <br /> Queen Poster Rails: 62.28"W x 84.02"D x 18.07"H - 37lbs.';

    $myArray = preg_split('/<br[^>]*>/i', $myString);

    print_r($myArray);
?>
```

**Outputs**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Overall Queen Poster 
    [1] =>  Queen Poster Headboard:
    [2] =>  Queen Poster 
    [3] =>  Queen Footboard  
    [4] =>  Queen Poster Rails: 62.28"W x 84.02"D x 18.07"H - 37lbs.
)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/73149)

**Limitations**:

Will split on any HTML tags that start with `br`. Meaning that if you made your own tag, such as `<breadcrumb>`, this would mistakenly be seen as a line break.

**Alternatives**:

- `explode('<br />', $myString)` if you're sure that your tags will always be exactly `<br />`
- `preg_split('/<br\s*/?>/i', $myString)` if you have tags such as `<breadcrumb>` and don't have any attributes in any `<br>` tag.

**Extra notes**:

If you don't want white-space in your matches, you can change your regex to `/<br[^>]*>\s*/i` which will also match any white-space characters after the match. Alternatively, you can run it through `ltrim` with `$myArray = array_map('ltrim', $myArray);`.

Answer (score 3):

The input is provided as a html encoded string so the line breaks are encoded as `<br />` so why don't you just take `<br />` as the separator instead of `\n` ?