# Strip html with regex, except tags that contains a character

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a program that imports emails to a database. To make the emails more readable in another program I have to strip it for html. I am using this string extension to strip the html.

```
public static string StripHtml(this string input)
{
   return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```

The problem is that when I copy forwarded mails, the email of the sender is written inside a tag.

< example@forwared.com >

Is there a way to use regex to remove all the tags, except tags that contains @ or an email?

The solution here is a possible way: [Remove html tags except <br> or <br/> tags with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708158/remove-html-tags-except-br-or-br-tags-with-javascript). But If there is a way to do it with just regex I prefer to do that.

Comment: try this `<[^@]*?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below `Regex` by adding an extra condition to your original regex to achieve your requirement:

```
<.[^@]*?>
```

Working Demo: https://regex101.com/r/CNOvS7/1/

Answer (score -1):

Use [^@]* instead of .*
It’s a character set of anything but @. The ^ stands for “not”. You could also do something like that [^0-9]* to exclude all numbers for example.